# CSS fast profile can be more fast when suppose ID as unique?

Tags: performance, algorithm, browser

The [CSS Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#profiles) introduced the concepts of *fast profile* and *complete profile*.

A "normal CSS-parser" [not suppose that `id` is unique](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127178/84349) (!), that is, the parser algorithm suppose that document have elements with `id` attribute with repeated (non-unique) values. So, in that "normal CSS-parsers"  the parsing of a CSS line like `#myID {...}` have the same algorithm that parsing `.myClass {...}`.  In the future, with a CSS4 standard and the *fast profile* adoption, the [render engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) will choose between "to parse *fast profile* document **faster**" or "to parse *complete profile* document".

It is a simple [computational performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) question...
**A  CSS-parsing algorithm of *fast profile***, parsing "good documents", **can be faster when suppose that document have unique IDs?**

---

## ... if you need more context

When I am implementing a CSS-parse with DOM, the answer is **yes**, because when parsing "good documents" (not ugly ones with repeated IDs) I can use [getElementById()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) method, that is faster (!)... But this question is not about DOM solutions, is about the algorithm used in the popular/serious *render engines* (like Blink, Geckoor or Webkit).

... **Summarizing** the possible optimizations with unique IDs (that we lost with non-unique IDs):

- Stop in the first element occurence of `id` value. 
  (and cache it in a hash). (and flag element with "hasID")
- Use a simple [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) to translate id values into element pointers. (cache in a hash).
- To use a (faster) method like `getElementById()` to resolve CSS lines like `#myID {...}`.
- ...
- Fast resolution  of [`:has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#relational) relational pseudo-class, when involving id's, like `:has(#myId)`... So, perhaps, we can add `:has(#myId)` to the *fast profile* definition!

... they are only my "personal hypothesis", may be not true for real life *render engines*, even when rendering good (not ugly) documents.

Comment: In July 2015, https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#profiles changed the terminology: "fast profile" now is *"dynamic (selector) profile"* and "complete profile" now is *"static (selector) profile"*.

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot here, I'm not sure where to start.  I guess the TL;DR is just a few quick points:

1. that things don't really work as it would appear you think they do, but that's pretty involved and I'm considering writing a post on it.
2. You misunderstand the intent/reason for the fast/complete profiles. I think probably the names are no help and I've recently [suggested we change them](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Apr/0070.html) to help avoid this particular kind of confusion - but understanding/really appreciating why it matters still requires an understanding of #1.
3. Because of this, it's actually the case that the change you are suggesting will decrease performance rather than increase it and will ultimately do nothing to change the real problems with `:has()`.

Trying to clarify in as few words as possible: CSS, that is, the part that applies styles does so against a dynamic tree including while it is still downloading and parsing the HTML.  It's difficult to illustrate very simply (I'll try in my post though if I ever get to finish it) but the sheer mathematics of a very simple approach explode like [The Towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi), it's absolutely necessary – at least if you actually want to view pages in the same way we always have –  that we retain certain aspects of the intelligent observations inherent in the existing constraints of CSS.  Literally all of those observations have to do with how rules relate to dynamic trees and how you can very quickly gain a handle on the mathematics by eliminating the number of elements you have to check and the number of rules you have to check them against based on the type of mutation (creating elements during parse is also considered a mutation) that has occurred. While you are writing JavaScript, however, you're evaluating a single rule against tree (or a part of a tree) just once as a snapshot in time and that's actually quite a different problem with a different answer to how to optimize it.  The short answer is: You don't really need to optimize it (actually, you couldn't optimize it much - the costs generally outweigh the benefits), it's actually really simple and fast.  Thus, things like querySelector or find have one strategy (tree walking) and dynamic or 'live' CSS has another (again, it's complicated and I'll try to explain it more elsewhere and link up if possible).

Given all this, evaluating something like `:has()` is actually really trivial to do in the case of querySelector, but it's completely unknown how to actually make this work in a live applying/dynamic tree.  We want to, it's just that no one has been able to figure out how to make it not suck.  Thus, what we have currently is "profiles".  Things like JavaScript, or maybe even print can support the Complete/Static Profile, but for now, browsers –  in terms of what you can write in a stylesheet and have applied dynamically –  can only support the Fast/Dynamic profile.  The suggestion is not, as you say, for the browser to choose whether they parse one profile or the other it's for one mode (the stuff you can write in a stylesheet) to support a subset and the other mode (the stuff you can evaluate once on a snapshot of the tree in JavaScript) to support the whole ball of wax.

All this said, I actually do think we can figure out how to make enough performance gains that on a reasonable tree with a reasonable number of rules and a few new expectations (display modes possibly) around partial rendering, it wouldn't suck.  I personally believe that if you can do that without hurting any existing pages, that's enough.  Opinions vary and so far fear of the worst case taking minutes to draw a page combined with so many other proposals and limited time have prevented too much progress on that front.

As to IDs specifically, changing what they mean would break existing pages without some kind of 'opt in' which really complicates things.  It's not just that they are 'ugly' it's that they are nearly impossible to avoid entirely and statistically it would seem that the current definition of "the first one in document order" is actually more useful/bulletproof in known cases and, while I realize it is counter-intuitive, it's also faster in the dynamic case, less memory intensive and only marginally slower (but more resilient) in the static case.  To illustrate why is not hard - if you start rendering a page and find an ID, you style it.  In your model if I reach the end of the document and find an ID, I have to go back and unstyle the previous one, deal with the repercussions and reflow and then come back and apply the style here.  The alternative (the current course) is to just apply them as encountered.  The real reason ID is special in CSS is because of specificity, it's simply 'more unique' so more important.  To CSS there is fundamentally no difference in the internals between attributes, classes and ids, they are merely about how we divvy up rules and winnow them down based on DOM mutation. In JavaScript, performance isn't so much the issue and browsers are expected to implement the Complete/Static profile including `:has()` with or without ID restrictions :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, the only comment that I can do is non-technical: I hate the culture of "repeated IDs", and I think that *W3C+browsers* can contribute to change this culture. *CSS4 profiles* seems to me a opportunity to tract this cultural problem. No matter if "original idea" of the *profiles* was other, it is (in my opinion) a  "2 in 1 solution" opportunity.

Comment: But, as I said, there is nothing in HTML that will make an id a unique thing either and that would actually be slower and break sites and more importantly _classes_ of sites (notably pages assembled from many authors) would be a lot less possible. Script APIs will do pretty much what you want, right?

I guess I'm having difficulty with the suggestion... Where is the value added by that proposal?  I mean, I see the preference, but what is the real value?

Comment: ... Yes, I agree, even if I list many, thousands of examples were unique-id is an important issue;  there remains some "personal taste" in my position... :-) Thanks again by your disposition to discuss this so "cryptic and personal"  theme.